# Pushing an object into an array creates an undefined error

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a store locator and need to create an array (called practitionersData) of objects with each object being a store. It works, but any object I push into the array doesn't work.

Here's how the code looks:

```js
let practitionersData = [];
practitionersData.push({
    "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis",
    "address": "3045 Excelsior Blvd",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Minneapolis",
    "state": "MN",
    "postal": "55416",
    "phone": "612-922-6662",
    "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
    "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
    "hours2": "",
    "hours3": "",
    "featured": "",
    "features": "",
    "lat": "44.947464",
    "lng": "-93.320826",                
    "date": "10/17/18",
    "formattedaddress":"3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
    }); 

let temperedOBJ = {
        "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis2",
        "address": "30451 Excelsior Blvd",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "Minneapolis",
        "state": "MN",
        "postal": "55416",
        "phone": "612-922-6662",
        "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
        "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
        "hours2": "",
        "hours3": "",
        "featured": "",
        "features": "",
        "lat": "44.947464",
        "lng": "-93.320826",                
        "date": "10/17/18",
        "formattedaddress":"3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
}

practitionersData.push(temperedOBJ);

console.log('==== start practitionersData =====')
console.log(practitionersData);
console.log(typeof practitionersData);            
console.log('==== start practitionersData 0 =====')
console.log(practitionersData[0]);     
console.log(typeof practitionersData[0]);            
console.log('==== start practitionersData 1 =====')
console.log(practitionersData[1]);                                                    
console.log(typeof practitionersData[1]);
```

The value and typeof practitionersData[0] looks fine and shows an object.
The value and typeof practitionersData[1] doesn't show in console and shows undefined.
If I look at the full array, I see the objects at each index.

Why does it stay an object when a push an object in, but become undefined if I'm pushing a variable representing an object?

Comment: There's only one call to `.push()` in the code you posted.

Comment: sry missed it in my original paste but its there. ideas?

Comment: Well your code works fine when you actually add the object to the array. Click the "Run code snippet" button and see for yourself.

Comment: you're right. It looks like my problem is somewhere else in my code. thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing just one object to the array. try to add `practitionersData.push(temperedOBJ)` before you use console.log()

Comment: sry I missed that in my original paste, but its there and have the problem still

Answer (score 1):

```
==== start practitionersData =====
[
  {
    "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis",
    "address": "3045 Excelsior Blvd",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Minneapolis",
    "state": "MN",
    "postal": "55416",
    "phone": "612-922-6662",
    "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
    "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
    "hours2": "",
    "hours3": "",
    "featured": "",
    "features": "",
    "lat": "44.947464",
    "lng": "-93.320826",
    "date": "10/17/18",
    "formattedaddress": "3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
  },
  {
    "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis2",
    "address": "30451 Excelsior Blvd",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Minneapolis",
    "state": "MN",
    "postal": "55416",
    "phone": "612-922-6662",
    "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
    "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
    "hours2": "",
    "hours3": "",
    "featured": "",
    "features": "",
    "lat": "44.947464",
    "lng": "-93.320826",
    "date": "10/17/18",
    "formattedaddress": "3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
  }
]
object
==== start practitionersData 0 =====
{
  "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis",
  "address": "3045 Excelsior Blvd",
  "address2": "",
  "city": "Minneapolis",
  "state": "MN",
  "postal": "55416",
  "phone": "612-922-6662",
  "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
  "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
  "hours2": "",
  "hours3": "",
  "featured": "",
  "features": "",
  "lat": "44.947464",
  "lng": "-93.320826",
  "date": "10/17/18",
  "formattedaddress": "3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
}
object
==== start practitionersData 1 =====
{
  "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis2",
  "address": "30451 Excelsior Blvd",
  "address2": "",
  "city": "Minneapolis",
  "state": "MN",
  "postal": "55416",
  "phone": "612-922-6662",
  "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
  "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
  "hours2": "",
  "hours3": "",
  "featured": "",
  "features": "",
  "lat": "44.947464",
  "lng": "-93.320826",
  "date": "10/17/18",
  "formattedaddress": "3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
}
object
```

Please look at the output I got after executing your code. I got the 'object' as output and not getting undefined.

Comment: you're right. It looks like my problem is somewhere else in my code. thanks for looking at it.